# Contact Prof for Course-Based Master Admission?

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school, masters

I am interested in applying course-based master program in electrical engineering. Most of them are self-funded, 1~1.5 years in length, and don't require a thesis .

I learnt that it is (usually) advantageous to contact the Prof of your interest in Phd application. Is this still true for application to course-based master degree？ Should I also try to contact Prof in order to "increase" my chance of admission? Is there any disadvantage of doing that?

As an undergrad, I think I have good research experience. (work in 3 different research lab, and produce 1 first-authored publication). Given that I have such experience, do you think it is advantageous for me to contact the Prof of my interested?

Answer (score 1):

I think it will depend on the structure of the Master's program. I'm assuming you'll still have to do some kind of comprehensive "project" which will require some kind of advisor. In which case, I think it would be helpful to get a willing professor beforehand to strengthen your application. It shows that you already have a direction you're interesting in pursuing (which would be aligned with the professor's research interests).

Answer (score 0):

There will be instructions on the program's website.

In the U.S., generally one applies to the department for admission before contacting a professor.